# Reshuffle Leagues to equal amounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a league system which a user can enter a public leagues per event.  The system will take the entry and add them to an available league where the league size has not been satisfied. As soon as a league is full the system will create a new league in the entry procedure and then the process fills this up and starts again.

5 minutes before the Event starts I lock down the event and then I am looking to perform a shuffle for the rooms to get them as equal as possible. One rule is that the user can exist only once per league but can enter many leagues per event i.e.

```
League1 (25 members max) For Event 1 = 25 members
League2 (25 members max) For Event 1 = 25 members
League3 (25 members max) For Event 1 = 4 members
```

I have a query which will return the leagues where their defined size has not been met which will give me:

```
LeagueID    EventID    LeagueSize    Remaining Players   FullRoomCount
3           1          25            4                   2
```

Where the full room count is the count of the number of rooms that have been satisfied

I am now trying to perform a shuffle of these rooms by re-assigning entries to another league.  This is my current method, pseudo-code:

- Get the fullRooms for this Event
- for each league in this event, get the noOfPlayers to add per league `(noOfPlayers = Math.Ceiling(remainingPlayers % FullRoomCount)` this will give me the number of players I need to assign to each league
- I then get the entrants for (which are the remaining players)
- I then loop each fullRoom and try to assign the player (if the user already exists then I need to get another league that applies)

My problem is the last point in this list. If the user exists in the league I am looping through already then this causes an issue where I need to find an alternate league and it breaks my ability to get these equal by using the `noOfPlayerstoAddPerLeague` variable.

```
// get the ratio of number of players to add to a league
Decimal noOfPlayerstoAddPerLeague = (Decimal)league.RemainingPlayers % (Decimal)league.FullRoomCount;

// get players in the remainder league
List<League_SelectEntriesResult> entriesToAssign = ctl.League_SelectEntries(league.LeagueID);

List<Int32> League_EntryIDCantAssign = new List<Int32>();
foreach(League_SelectEntriesResult entry in entriesToAssign)
{
    // get the leagues that are full
    List<League_GetFullRoomsResult> fullRooms = ctl.League_GetFullRooms(meetingID);

    // loop leages until all entries satisfied
    foreach(League_GetFullRoomsResult room in fullRooms)
    {
        // any entries left?
        if(entriesToAssign.Count == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        // assign user if possible
        if(ctl.League_Entry_Reassign(entry.League_EntryID, entry.LeagueID, entry.UserID, room.LeagueID))
        {
            break;
        }

        // if we got this far then the user has not been assigned
        // add the users we cannot re-assign to this list
        League_EntryIDCantAssign.Add(entry.League_EntryID);
    }
}
```